# .NET threading returns value?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, return-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning a value from thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314155/returning-a-value-from-thread)

I have this code:

```
//Asynchronously start the Thread to process the Execute command request.
Thread objThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteCommandSync));
//Make the thread as background thread.
objThread.IsBackground = true;
//Set the Priority of the thread.
objThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
//Start the thread.
objThread.Start(command);
```

The problem is that `ExecuteCommandSync` returns a string.

How can i capture the string that is returned and return it?

Comment: assign the string on class level variable (field)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314155/returning-a-value-from-thread

Comment: You're going to need an IAsyncResult to share data between threads.  but by its nature an async function cannot return data.   I can write you a sample for safely sharing data between threads.  What application type is this Console?  WinForm? WPF? Web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) if the callback returns something. Try the following:

```
Thread objThread = new Thread(state => 
{
    string result = ExecuteCommandSync(state);
    // TODO: do something with the returned result
});
//Make the thread as background thread.
objThread.IsBackground = true;
//Set the Priority of the thread.
objThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
//Start the thread.
objThread.Start(command);
```

Also notice that `objThread.Start` starts the thread and returns immediately. So make sure that the hosting process doesn't end before the thread finishes executing as because you made it a background thread it will be aborted. Otherwise don't make it background thread.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend looking into the TPL in .NET 4.  It would allow you to do:

```
Task<string> resultTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => ExecuteCommandSync(state) );
```

Later, when you need the result, you can access it (which will block if the method isn't completed), by doing:

```
string results = resultTask.Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Threading in C# by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

you can do :

```
static int Work(string s) { return s.Length; }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Func<string, int> method = Work;
  IAsyncResult cookie = method.BeginInvoke ("test", null, null);
  //
  // ... here's where we can do other work in parallel...
  //
  int result = method.EndInvoke (cookie);
  Console.WriteLine ("String length is: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The thread runs in the background, and only finishes some time after the rest of your code.