# Can std::async be use with template functions

Tags: c++, templates, asynchronous, c++11, std

Is [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) supose to work with template function? I've tried to lauch [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) as an asynchronous task bu got compile-time error.

I've tried to use simpler functions (foo and bar) and discover that only the non-template-function are working.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <future>
#include <string>

void foo(std::string::iterator first, std::string::iterator last)
{
}

template<class BidirectionalIterator>
void bar(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet";

    auto result_reverse = std::async(std::reverse, str.begin(), str.end()); // Compile-time error
    auto result_foo     = std::async(foo, str.begin(), str.end());
    auto result_bar     = std::async(bar, str.begin(), str.end()); // Compile-time error

    result_reverse.get();
    result_foo.get();
    result_bar.get();
}
```

The compiler error is as follow:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:18:71: erreur: no matching function for call to ‘async(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator)’
main.cpp:18:71: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/future:1355:5: note: template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/future:1378:5: note: template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Functor>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
main.cpp:18:71: erreur: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
main.cpp:20:62: erreur: no matching function for call to ‘async(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator)’
main.cpp:20:62: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/future:1355:5: note: template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/future:1378:5: note: template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> typename std::__async_sfinae_helper<typename std::decay<_Functor>::type, _Fn, _Args ...>::type std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
main.cpp:20:62: erreur: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

However, it pass when I manually specify the template instanciation, such as `std::async(std::reverse<std::string::iterator>, str.begin(), str.end())`.

Is this a compiler bug (GCC 4.6.3) or a well defined behaviour?

Comment: Templates aren't functions, so the behaviour is correct according to the standard. If you want deduced arguments, you need to wrap it in a functor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can, but the invocation is a bit different:

```
auto result_reverse = std::async([&str]() {
        std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    });
```

This is because `std::reverse()` is not a function, rather a function template that turns into a function when it is invoked as a function.

The above reverses a copy of the string and throws away the result. To pass the string by reference the lambda expression should be changed to start with `[&str]()`.

Comment: +1, but this will essentially do nothing, you should pass `str` by reference.

Comment: You're right, it reverses a copy of a string and throws away the result. I assumed this is just an example of using a function template.

Comment: Why is there a mutable keyword between the lambda parameter list and it's body?

Comment: @authchir lambda's object `operator()` is const by default which makes variables captured by value const as well. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5501959/412080

Answer (score 8):

`std::reverse` is not a function but a function template, you can use an specialization of that template (which is a function):

```
auto result_reverse = std::async(&std::reverse<std::string::iterator>, str.begin(), str.end());
```

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, the function name will implicitly decay into a pointer to function in this context. I still prefer to explicitly ask for it when dealing with function pointers... absurd, since I don't do that for array->pointer decay...