# execute function in C++ after a delay without using sleep

Tags: c++, delay, delayed-execution

is there a simple way of making something happen after a specific delay in C++?
In python, I just use frame.after(ms,myFunction) which is nice and easy - it seems like a far trickier problem in C++!
It has previously been suggested that I use Sleep(), unfortunately this doesn't work as I am writing a mod for Half-Life 2 and if I use Sleep then the whole game hangs for X seconds rather than just calling the event after X seconds.
So is there another way to call a function after a specific delay without using sleep?

Comment: [`std::async()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) with `std::this_thread::sleep()`? Is that acceptable?

Comment: Assuming that `frame.after(ms, myFunction)` is part of the Python API for Half-Life mods, then there must be a C++ equivalent, and that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have 2 options imho:

1. Create a second `thread` which will sleep instead of your main `thread`.
2. Create a second `thread` which contains a timer.

I can only recommend [boosts io_service](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html)

You might want to go through all the [timer tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html#boost_asio.tutorial.basic_skills) if you're new to boost.

---

If you want to stay with the `std` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963172/why-using-stdasync-from-c11) for more information on `std::async`

And [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/540912/Cplusplus-Threads-Make-your-multitasking-life-e) for a guide on how to use `std::threads`

Answer (score 0):

**Why not using a thread with a timer?**
Check this site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40915/simple-multithread-timer