# C# Task.Run() vs. C++ std::async()

Tags: c#, c++, concurrency

I am running on my Mac 2 similar code samples, one in C++, another in C#. 2 simple tasks that execute in parallel (or at least I want them to), one printing '+' in a loop, the other printing '-' in a loop. I was expecting the output from the 2 samples to be quite similar, but they are quite a bit different to my surprise.

C++ seems to truly run the tasks in parallel. I can see +- alternating nicely on every run, but C# seems to run one task for a while, then switch to the other task and run that for a while. Something like this:

```
C++: +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
C# : ++++++++++---------++++++------
```

I understand assumptions cannot be made about how parallel threads are run, it's just curious to me that C++ produces such a nice result, consistently.

Thanks for your time!

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ConcurrentTasks
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run(()=>DemoTask("+"));
        var task2 = Task.Run(()=>DemoTask("-"));
        var res1 = task1.Result;
        var res2 = task2.Result;
        Console.WriteLine("\nResults:");
        Console.WriteLine(res1);
        Console.WriteLine(res2);
    }

    private static String DemoTask(String label)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(label);
        }

        return label + " result";
    }
}

// mcs ConcurrentTasks.cs
// mono ConcurrentTasks.exe
```

C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

string demoTask(char label)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        cout << label;
    }

    stringstream ss;
    ss << label;
    ss << " result";
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    auto task1 = async(demoTask, '+');
    auto task2 = async(demoTask, '-');
    auto res1 = task1.get();
    auto res2 = task2.get();
    cout << endl << "Results:" << endl;
    cout << res1 << endl;
    cout << res2 << endl;
    return 0;
}

// g++ --std=c++14 -Wall ConcurrentTasks.cpp -o ConcurrentTasks.exe
// ./ConcurrentTasks.exe
```

Edit: I've changed the C# sample to use bare Thread and the result is the same.

C# with Thread:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class ConcurrentTasks
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var t1 = new Thread(() => DemoTask("+"));
        var t2 = new Thread(() => DemoTask("-"));
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    private static String DemoTask(String label)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(label);
        }

        return label + " result";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Task.Run` runs the task on a threadpool thread. As usually with multithreading, no assumptions can be made about order of execution of two threads unless explicit synchronization mechanisms are used.

Comment: Yes, according to documentation, both should use a thread pool. Anyway, I've reworked the C# example to use Thread. Same result.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the thread comes from a threadpool or not, it only matters that there are separate threads. When there are separate threads, you cannot expect them to execute in any particular order unless you explicitly synchronize them.

Comment: I am aware of that, it's just curious to me that the results are so different between the languages and was hoping for someone to give an explanation on that, the difference between the languages with regard to this sample.

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/q/17963172/11683 will be helpful (regarding `std::launch::async` and `std::launch::deferred`).

Comment: Different languages. Different implementations of threads, locks, scheduling, thread pools, IO mechanisms, etc etc. Different results. Colour me *not* surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like C#'s console had the biggest impact.

I've modified the C# sample yet again, to not use the console while executing the 2 tasks. Instead I use a shared output char array. The results are dramatically different, very close to C++, although not as perfect and consistent.

It's amazing how the C++ program produces perfect +- pairs on every run, even with the cout in use. The C# output is each time slightly different and often I still see one thread finishing before the next starts. I had to increase significantly the number of iterations because with a small number of iterations the tasks ran in sequence always.

Here's the updated C# sample (note the interlocked increment!):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ConcurrentTasks
{
    private static char[] m_out;
    private static int m_index = -1;

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var iterations = 5000;
        m_out = new char[iterations * 2];
        var task1 = Task.Run(()=>DemoTask(iterations, '+'));
        var task2 = Task.Run(()=>DemoTask(iterations, '-'));
        var res1 = task1.Result;
        var res2 = task2.Result;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_out.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(m_out[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nResults:");
        Console.WriteLine(res1);
        Console.WriteLine(res2);
    }

    private static String DemoTask(int iterations, char label)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            int index = Interlocked.Increment(ref m_index);
            m_out[index] = label;
        }

        return label + " result";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Granularity could be one reason. TPL may have *coarse* granularity which scheduling the tasks, but C++ `async` implementation might have *fine* granularity. This essentially means C++ would be taking more time, since just for processing `+` or `-` it is scheduling another task in between.

Another reason could be how `cout` and `Console` have implemented the output streams. How the locks might be taken to render something on screen? Any buffering being implemented? You see, `Console.Write` may be buffering, and then printing after a while, but `cout` may just be printing it immediately.

Hence, you should do something else, rather than depending on underlying I/O of the language - may be put the character on a shared static-sized array with shared `int`  as index to shared array (<del>they are atomic, don't need locks</del> Lock it with lightest synchronization primitive like reader-writer lock). No, don't use `vector` or `Array` - because in that case you are again *dependent* on something you don't know!

Use Release build in both cases, with best-possible same optimization options. Also, ensure you are running them on same machine.

Comment: The shared int index _may_ need use atomic semantics explicitly, since without them code like `globalIndex++` may take the current value (read atomically) into registers for the current thread, increment it and then write it out (atomically); while the other thread might have updated it behind the scenes. Unless the CPU has an instruction of the form `increment variable at memory address [x]` _and_ the compiler always uses it for ints that are not explicitly said to require atomicity, the behaviour you mention cannot be trusted.

Comment: @JavierMartín, you are right. `volatile` may also have same problem. Better to use lightest locking mechanism