# C++ std::async - Is it just syntactic sugar for launching threads?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, future

## `std::future`, `std::promise` and `std::thread`s

I am trying to get my head around a few of the newer C++ concepts such as `std::future`, `std::promise` and `std::async`.

I think I understand pretty well how futures and promises work. They are a apir of classes/objects which can be used to pass data to and from threads in a convenient manner. In summary they work like this:

- Create a promise defining the type of data to be returned
- Create a future for the created promise using `promise.get_future()`
- Launch a thread, moving the promise into the thread function
- Parent thread continues to do other work until result from launched thread function is required, at which point parent waits for result by calling `future.get()`.
- If result has already been "set", parent thread continues, else it goes to sleep for an indefinite/infinite/unlimited (?) time
- If result has not been "set", child thread continues working
- Child thread sets the promise value using `promise.set_value()`
- This prompts parent thread to wake up if it was sleeping
- Typically child thread would then exit, parent thread would call `thread.join()` and continue working

(One of my favorite examples can be found here: https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/promise-and-future)

Therefore the promise future construct provides a way to launch a thread and return a result while keeping the parent and child threads synchronized at the points in program execution when this is required.

## `std::async`

Here is where I get confused. I have read several documentation pages regarding `std::async`. What confuses me is that I usually associate `future` with `promise`. But when using `std::async` there is no mention of a promise at any point. Is it hidden by the implementation?

Here's a selection of documentation pages:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async
- https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/
- https://thispointer.com/c11-multithreading-part-9-stdasync-tutorial-example/
- [Why should I use std::async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963172/why-should-i-use-stdasync)
- https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/30411/std--future-and-std--async
- https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/17/cpp-11-async-tutorial/

As far as I can tell, `std::async` does the following:

- Launches a thread, returning a `std::future` object
- (Has different launch modes, can be "deferred" meaning the thread does not start work until the result is requested, and "async" meaning the thread starts work immediatly)
- When the result is required, `future.get()` is called.
- Since there is no `promise` involved in this process, I would have assumed that it is not possible to return a value from a `promise` using `future.get()`...
- However, some examples indicated that the return type is defined by the function to be called with `async`. The value then is returned by `future.get()`. So it *is* possible to return a value, but no `std::promise` in sight?

Edit: Here's another article which gives details of futures, promises, async and also packaged tasks. It provides some explanations as to why you might use different options, but at the end states the difference between async and launching a thread with future/promise is that the returned value can be set anywhere within the thread function execution rather than just at the end by a `return` statement.

https://ncona.com/2018/02/futures-async-packaged_tasks-and-promises-in-c/

## Questions

- Why use `async` instead of a `future` `promise` pair?
- Is `async` just syntactic sugar for launching a thread while hiding the `promise` from view of the programmer?

In other words, my question is what is the difference between using `async` to launch a seperate thread and doing it by explicitly using `std::thread` with `promise` and `future`.

- Are they *functionally*, the same?

Answer (score 1):

> Why use `async` instead of a `future` `promise` pair?

Because it is one thing, instead of three + orchestration. Or because your implementation does it with a thread pool, rather than a new thread each time. Or because you want `deferred` or *implementation-defined* launch policy.

> Is `async` just syntactic sugar for launching a thread while hiding the `promise` from view of the programmer?

On some implementations, yes. On others it can run the function on a thread-pool thread. It just has to ensure that reachable `thread_local` data is fresh for each invocation.

> Are they functionally, the same?

In the sense that

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
std::future<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>> async(F f, Args... args) {
    std::promise<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>> prom;
    auto fut = prom.get_future();
    std::thread([p = std::move(prom)](F f, Args... args) { p.set_value_at_thread_exit(f(args...)); }, f, args...).detach();
    return fut;
}
```

is *approximately* what `std::async` does?