# How to get a return value from a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Lets say a function,

```
int fun(){
    static int a = 10;
    a = a+1;
    return a;
}
```

The above function is returning a integer value,

```
//Without thread obtaining return value
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int var = 0;
    var = fun();
    std::cout << "The value " << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now is there any possible way to get the returned value when invoked by C++11 thread,

```
//Using thread
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(fun);//Invoking thread
    //How to obtain the return value of the thread ?
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `int return_of_t1; std::thread t1([&return_of_t1]{return_of_t1 = fun();});`

Comment: BTW, calling `fun` from different threads will result in ultimate chaos.

Comment: Ok got it we can use lambda function, i think we can avoid the chaos by using a locking mechanism.

Comment: `std::async` was desgined to do job like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Simple return value from std::thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686939/c-simple-return-value-from-stdthread)

Comment: Not immediately relevant but note that `a` should really be `std::atomic<int>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For obtaining return values form functions that are meant to be run in background, you may want to consider [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) instead of directly creating an `std::thread` object. You can use the [`std::async()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) function template to start an *asynchronous* task. It returns an `std::future` object that will eventually contain the return value of the function passed:

```
auto res = std::async(fun);

// ... optionally do something else

std::cout << res.get() << '\n';
```

That is, you create an `std::future<int>` by calling `std::async(func)`. Then, when you need `fun()`'s return value, you simply call the `get()` member function on the future. If the future isn't *ready* yet (i.e., if it doesn't have the result yet), then the thread will block until it is.

---

#### Why not directly use `std::thread`

The problem with `std::thread` is that it doesn't provide a direct mechanism for transferring the return value of the callable passed at its construction. For example, suppose you want to start a new thread with `std::thread` to calculate the sum of two integers with the following function:

```
int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

What you would probably try is:

```
std::thread th_sum(sum, 1, 2);

// ... optionally do something else

th_sum.join();
// calculation is finished, but where is the result?
```

The thread represented by `th_sum` does calculate the sum of *1* and *2*. However, you don't get `sum()`'s return value, i.e., the result, from the associated `std::thread` object.

Instead, what you could do to handle this deficiency is, for example, to create a wrapper function for `sum()` that has an *out parameter* for the result instead of returning it:

```
void sum_outparam(int a, int b, int& res) { res = sum(a, b); }
```

Then, you can start a new thread for running this wrapper function and with help of [`std::ref()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) you will obtain the result in `res`:

```
int res;
std::thread th_sum(sum_outparam, 1, 2, std::ref(res));

// ... optionally do something else


th_sum.join();
// now, res contains the result
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async`, a promised future (pun intended) or packaged task.

```
// future from a packaged_task
std::packaged_task<int()> task(fun); // wrap the function
std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();  // get a future
std::thread(std::move(task)).detach(); // launch on a thread

// future from an async()
std::future<int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, fun);

// future from a promise
std::promise<int> p;
std::future<int> f3 = p.get_future();
std::thread( [](std::promise<int>& p){ p.set_value(fun()); },
             std::ref(p) ).detach();


std::cout << "Waiting...";
f1.wait();
f2.wait();
f3.wait();
std::cout << "Done!\nResults are: "
          << f1.get() << ' ' << f2.get() << ' ' << f3.get() << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `std::thread` is just a simple C++ wrapper that allows to start an OS thread of execution and wait until it's done.

To share the return value with the calling thread, you can either manually provide the thread with a shared state, or use a higher-level facilities like [`packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task), [`future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) etc.