# How to Return Thread result

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, linq, wcf

How would I go about returning the "**var T**" like the "**var result**" in the example below(code comments) in the new Thread that I created?

```
public QuoteResult GetQuote(QuoteData Data)
{
    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        const int stackSize = 8000000;
        var T = new Thread(() => CalculateRates(db, Data), stackSize);
        T.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        T.Start();
        T.Join();

        //var result = CalculateRates(db, Data);
        //return result; //Example of how I want it in the new thread created above
    }
}
```

My ***CalculateRates*** method coding:

```
public QuoteResult CalculateRates(TruckDb db, QuoteData data)
{
    var result = new QuoteResult
    {
        Successful = false,
        Data = data
    };

    List<QuoteItemSectionGroup> quoteItems = new List<QuoteItemSectionGroup>();

    var quoteItem = new QuoteItem
    {
        ChassisModel = db.ChassisModel.Find(data.ChassisId),
        ChassisManufacturer = db.ChassisManufacturer.Find(data.ChassisManufacturerId),
        BodyType = db.BodyTypes.Find(data.BodyTypeId),
        //...10 lines more
    };

    //...unnecessary to see codes and calculations...

    result.QuoteItem = quoteItem;
    result.Successful = true;
    return result;
}
```

I just need to run my CalculateRates method in a new thread to increase the stack size. If you need any more code or information, please don't hesitate to ask. Thank you!

Comment: see also : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1314155/327083  Many of these don't directly apply since you seem to want a distincly synchronous operation (ie: the thread's purpose is not for background work), but it's worth reading for ideas just the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is

```
QuoteResult qr = null;
var T = new Thread(() => qr = CalculateRates(db, Data), stackSize);
T.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
T.Start();
T.Join();
return qr;
```

Alternatively, another way to do this, in this context, is to use an `out` parameter instead of a function return value.  This is of particular use if you need to return more than one value.

```
public void CalculateRates(TruckDb db, QuoteData data, out QuoteResult qrResult)
{
    qrResult= new QuoteResult
    {
        Successful = false,
        Data = data
    };    

    //...unnecessary to see codes and calculations...

    qrResult.QuoteItem = quoteItem;
    qrResult.Successful = true;        
}
```

Then call as :

```
 QuoteResult qr = null;
 var T = new Thread(() => CalculateRates(db, Data, out qr), stackSize);
 T.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
 T.Start();
 T.Join();
 return qr;
```

In both cases the `null` initialization is necessary because the compiler cannot see across the thread boundary to determine that a value has actually been assigned.  Without the `.Join` call, for example, it's quite likely that a value would not yet have been assigned so you have to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment man! :) I get the error: *Use of unassigned local variable 'qr'* when running your code

Comment: @CareTaker22 You can initialize it with null and compiler error would disappear.

Comment: An alternative is do simply set the value inside your method you've passed to the thread. For example: `new Thread(() => qr = CalculateRates(new object()), stackSize);`. Saves you having to modify the `CalculateRates` method.

Comment: @Rob Worth an answer if you'd care to post it.  Didn't think about that myself.

Comment: @Rob Yes please, could you post your answer still?

Comment: @CareTaker22 I've added Rob's suggestion to my answer in the meantime.

Comment: @Rob If you do post an answer, ping me and I'll revert the addition ;)

Comment: @J... Your answer works and I can now calculate my values correctly. Thank you very much! :D The Only thing now is that *qr* returns **null**? The values that I need are in **Data** and not in **qr** :(

Comment: @CareTaker22 This sounds like the subject for a new question.  Most likely what is happening is that you are only holding a reference to `Data` in the `QuoteResult` and not to the parent `TruckDb` - since you are using a `using` statement, `db` is falling out of scope and being disposed.  You may need to copy the `Data` object rather than just hold a reference.